# Is it possible with Angularjs directive to watch vars in dynamic controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a service that's being used in different controllers, and I would like to consolidate them into a directive that can be applied to the different pages. To start, I'm just trying to get a simple example to work. Say I have two controllers, both of which have a common function:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('CtrlOne', function() {
    $scope.watchVar = 0;
    $scope.changeVar = function() {
        $scope.watchVar = 1;
    }
});

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('CtrlTwo', function() {
    $scope.watchVar = a;
    $scope.changeVar = function() {
        $scope.watchVar = b;
    }
});
```

Then, in a directive I'm trying to determine the controller at runtime, so that this variable can be watched regardless of the controller the page has (as long as it uses the 'watchVar' variable):

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            ctrl: '@myDirective',
            watchVar: '=',
        },
        controller: ctrl,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('watchVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    console.log("watchVar changed to: "+newValue);
                } else {
                    console.log("watchVar remained: "+oldValue);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

With the HTML being something like this:

```
<div p2a-filter-cache='CtrlOne'>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not just pass the variable to watch?

Comment: @FrankModica I'm definitely not married to my current approach if there's an easier way to do it...I'm a bit new to all this, do you mind elaborating just a bit?

Comment: I'd think your current approach would work as is (you can remove `ctrl: '@myDirective'`). Pass in the variable to watch: `<div my-directive watch-var="watchVar"></div>`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now - that works but in reality though there will be a bunch of variables I'll need to work with so I was hoping for something someone could easily drop into an HTML template and only have to know the controller name vs. all the variable names. If there's no other way though it will do in a pinch.

Comment: Oh so you were planning on not having `watchVar`, only the controller name?

Comment: My guess is that `<div my-directive ctrl="this"></div>` won't work. But if you switch to `controller as` syntax and bind data to the controller (instead of `$scope`) you might be able to reference the controller that way. Because when you do that, the controller itself has a name in the template.

Comment: Good tip - let me try that and get back, thanks!

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, you could always just do `$scope.ctrl = this`, and then `<div my-directive ctrl="ctrl"></div>`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant but I tried this:         scope: {
            ctrl: '@myDirective'
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',          but while it didn't cause an error, it didn't seem to work either.  Let me try your other suggestion that looks promising...

Comment: When I try that I get an error 'Cannot read property 'match' of undefined, though I'm not sure I've implemented this the way you intended. Formatting the HTML the same way as in your example, in the directive I tried scope: { ctrl: this } was that what you meant?

Comment: I meant in your parent controller (like `CtrlOne`) you do `$scope.myCtrl = this`. The directive definition then defines the variable to take in, like `scope: { ctrl: '=' }`. Then you pass the controller from parent to child like this: `<div my-directive ctrl="myCtrl"></div>`

Comment: Might want to create a live example if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I created a Plunkr for it but this is my first attempt at sharing one, can you see this: https://plnkr.co/edit/AqwPKTnE0bqHt9NLPPeW

Comment: It's a little bit different in that I've got a button to change the watched var but it captures the gist of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's not running for me because Angular isn't loaded, but I meant something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/emxC8avu55fQL9UeHZlB?p=preview

Comment: Sorry about that, this one should look better, and incorporates your suggestion: https://plnkr.co/edit/nUGQ4F7QRG8OucEFmfsn

Comment: I switched to my first suggestion, which is the controller as syntax: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/NRjDTvu01MhyaGIYMn8h?p=preview. Passing around whole controllers is pretty awkward though!

Comment: Yeah I'm not even sure this is possible to do in a clean way...the HTML in question in real life is a template defined in another directive, which complicates things further. I'm not sure I can assign a specific controller to the HTML, so I was hoping there was some way to 'pass' the controller to this new directive and have it look it up or otherwise resolve it, but I may be thinking of this in the wrong way.

Comment: Yes it sounds like there might be an architectural issue. Usually, the highest level controllers should "own" the data and know how to retrieve and modify it. Directives should usually just take data as parameters (and not really know where the data comes) and fire events.

Comment: What I'm trying to do does work if I keep the functions inside the controllers themselves, I was just hoping for a neat solution where I could just apply the behavior at the HTML level and contain it in a directive for that reason. It does work as is though, so I may have to settle for that solution, at least for now. Thanks for all your help though, I really appreciate the insights!